# How Can I open a certain Mac application[which is Developed by me] via clicking on a Safari toolbar item?

Tags: macos, cocoa, safari-extension

I am new to Mac application development. I've developed a small Mac application as well as a safari extension. I've used extension builder to build that particular toolbar item:

[image]

The problem is that when the user clicks on toolbar item, the certain Mac application triggers, any Suggestion or hint or tutorial for it?

Comment: What exactly is going wrong, what kind of credentials are these? Your question title asks how you can open an external app; but you seem to have implemented that.

Comment: in sort, when the user clicks on that safari toolbar item, I want to open a mac application which is developed by me

Comment: Ok, so you edited your question. You need to look-up the target app by its bundle identifier, like `com.example.your-app` which is set in the Xcode project. Does `NSWorkspace.launchApplication(withBundleIdentifier:options:additionalEventParamDescriptor:launchIdentifier:)` work from the extension?